# What's the execCommand for shift+Enter?

Tags: wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, execcommand

Y'know how ctrl+B is equivalent to exec('bold')? What's the equivalent for shift+Enter? `insertBrOnReturn` isn't quite right, and besides, it's [not supported on most browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_compatibility).

Reason I'm looking for this is that I want mobile users to be able to create a `<br>` when they don't want the big gap that comes with a `<p>`